# Why is my return type wrong?

Tags: java, netbeans, return-type

So I am trying to work out how inheritance works. I made a basicclass called 'Mens' and a subclass called 'Leerkracht'.
Mens has one method called 'toon' which ofc is inherited by its subclass. 
The problem is that Netbeans doesn' allow me to use 'void' for return type with the inherited method in the subclass and I have absolutly no clue why.

Mens class :

```
public class Mens {
private String naam;

public Mens(String naam){
    this.naam=naam;
}
public void toon(){
    System.out.println(this.naam);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Leerkracht class:

```
public class Leerkracht extends Mens{

public Leerkracht(String naam) {
    super(naam);
}

@Override
public void toon(){
    System.out.println("dit is een leerkracht"+ super.toon());
// the error is on the line above which states ''void' type not allowed here'

}
```

}

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: your class structure is not proper. you are executing Mens which is base class and what are you doing in main block not clear.

Comment: @gyanu his class structure is proper.

Comment: @gyanu: that is irrelevant and nothing wrong with. the problem is explained in the answers below: he calls super.toon() in a print statement, in a String concatenation, but it returns nothing to concatenate.

Comment: ok got it but having main function on base class i don't think he will make good use of  derived class Leerkracht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println("dit is een leerkracht"+ super.toon());
```

Since the `toon()` method in the super class doesn't return anything(its return type is `void`), you cannot provide it within a SOP(print statement). Because the SOP(print statement) expects a value to be returned by that method, which would be concatenated and printed on the System console.

The `toon()` method in `Mens` class anyways has a SOP(print statement), so you can do something like this to print your contents.

```
@Override
public void toon(){
    System.out.print("dit is een leerkracht"); // note that I made this to print so that the name which is printed within super.toon() stays in the same line
    super.toon();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the method `toon()` of your superclass by using `super.toon()`.

Since `toon()` is a void-method, it doesn't return anything. Remove it and your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void toon(){
    System.out.println("dit is een leerkracht");
// no error anymore

}
```